# Why does $ \sum_{i=0}^n \theta_i X_i = \theta^TX$ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

While reading Machine learning, I came through a formula, which is

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n \theta_i X_i = \theta^TX .$$

I would like to know the name of the equation and some explanation behind it.

Comment: In terms of wording, most compactly you'd call this: a finite linear combination of the $X_i$ or alternatively: an inner product of the vector $\mathbf{\Theta}$ and $\mathbf{X}$ written as $\langle \mathbf{\Theta}, \mathbf{X} \rangle$ or $\mathbf{\Theta}\cdot \mathbf{X}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have seen this formula in the context of matrices. Here $\theta$ and $X$ are $(n+1)\times 1$ matrices, with

$$\theta=\begin{bmatrix}
 \theta_0 \\
 \theta_1 \\
 \theta_2 \\
 \vdots \\
 \theta_n \\
\end{bmatrix},\quad
X=\begin{bmatrix}
 X_0 \\
 X_1 \\
 X_2 \\
 \vdots \\
 X_n \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then $\theta^\mathsf{T}$ is the "transpose" of $\theta$, the $1\times (n+1)$ matrix that swaps the rows and columns of the original matrix.

The overall formula is a statement of matrix multiplication. It also shows an alternate way of writing the "dot product" of two column vectors.

Do I need to clarify any of the terminology I used? If you don't understand summation notation, column vectors, matrix multiplication, or the dot product, you should review the basics before you get back to where you saw that formula.

Comment: It looks like it is good idea for me to go back to under-grad days and refresh the basics once more. Thanks for answering.

Comment: OP indexing starts at zero. Edited.

Comment: @GEdgar: Oops, I missed that. Thanks! I did one little edit after you did yours.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for citing this.... :)